# Sound effects pre-bootloader

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, audio, boot

I have an Asus laptop, and when it boots up (but before the bootloader) it makes a sound.

When I have headphones plugged into the jack, and I had shut down from ubuntu, the sound goes to the headphones. If I had just shut down from windows, the sound goes to the speakers.

What gives? If possible, I would like the sound to always go to the headphones.

Comment: What kind of sound, a beep? Have you tried looking in your BIOS settings for an option to disable the sound?

Comment: Its a boom I guess you can call it. It is not a beep code or anything like that. As far as I can tell, there is nothing in the BIOS settings that deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to modify the Windows driver for the sound card to inhibit resetting the audio hardware before unloading.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I like the way that linux does it, and I want to make windows behave in the same manner.

Comment: Oh, whoops. Well, the solution is still mostly the same.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: The problem now is that *you* can't. You'll need to talk to whoever wrote the driver.